# Enumerate handles open by process using process id or name without NtQueryInformationProcess

Tags: windows, visual-c++, handle

Is there any way to know handle/handles open by any process if we know process id and name without using any API from ntdll.dll e.g. NtQueryInformationProcess.

Comment: Do you want not to use functions from _ntdll.dll_ directly or altogether (if it's the 2nd case, I think it's nearly impossible, since even if there are some other APIs, most likely that they end up calling functions from this dll). Is there a reason for this (as _ntdll.dll_ is loaded by every running app)?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to use functions from ntdll.dll altogether since in upcoming updates of windows 10 functions from ntdll.dll will not work.

Comment: No.  Windows provides no supported mechanism for doing this, so your only option is the unsupported mechanisms.  If a particular unsupported mechanism only works on some versions of Windows, you'll need to check which version you're running on and adjust accordingly.